# V2 Domain RSA Private not working

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I'm trying to connecting venify v2 domain with tor hidden_service. I'm using `eschalot` and `shallot` for generate domains. but when I change domain name in hostname and replace private_key. It stop working. when I restart tor service. hostname being replaced with v3 domain. I'm sorry for so basic question. Please help to connect v2 domain with hosting.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tor version it is either hidden service v2 or v3 which is the default. And I think it is v3 in your case.

Try putting:

```
HiddenServiceVersion 2
```

in your hidden service definition and retry.

Please also note that hidden service v2 support will be removed from tor network in the near future (this year if I remember correctly) so you should consider moving to v3 right now.

Comment: Should I create directory ?